# What are the geographic locations depicted in Windows Aero theme?

Tags: windows-7, windows, aero

Does anyone know the geographic locations of photos displayed in Windows' 7 Aero theme, specifically for `United States` and `Landscapes` themes? I need to visit these places.

Comment: Are [these backgrounds](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/united-states-download-theme) the ones that you are referring to?

Comment: That appears to be an extra download, although it does has location references, perfect, thx

Comment: Whenever I ask interesting questions like these I get nasty comments about how it "isn't a question about a PC problem". I've always wondered the same thing! :)

Comment: @moses I <3 inquisitive people.

Comment: @moses From my perspective, it was most certainly a PC problem :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the screenshot below, this is how, as far as I can tell.

[image]

Comment: Sweet, but very subtle :-D

Comment: @SAFX, the screenshot is fairly small. You able to read it alright? I can post a larger image if need be.

Comment: Nahh, I'm good, I got the gist of it, thank you

Comment: Here's a direct link to the full-size image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pjDII.jpg